# Choose the pattern in regexprep

Tags: regex, string, matlab

I have a string in Matlab and a want to replace the third appearance of some pattern in it with another pattern. How can I do this?

For example:

```
str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-ter-hg';
patternRemove = 'ter';
patternAdd = 'mov';
```

answer:

```
str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-mov-hg';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-ter-hg';
patternRemove = 'ter';
patternAdd = 'mov';

ind = regexp(str,patternRemove);
ii = ind(3);
strOut = [str(1:ii-1) patternAdd str(ii+numel(patternRemove):end)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't be of more help to you, but I do not know how you'd go about it in Matlab.  If I were trying to solve this problem, this is how I'd do it.

```
<?php

$i = 0; // SET A DEFAULT VALUE FOR OUR COUNTER
$str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-ter-hg-ter-as-b-ter-a-sdf-w-ter-s-ter-asd'; // TEXT TO WORK ON
$remove = 'ter'; // TEXT TO REPLACE EACH THIRD OCCURRENCE OF 
$replace = 'mov'; // TEXT TO REPLACE EACH THIRD OCCURRENCE WITH

// USE A CALLBACK FUNCTION TO CHECK TO SEE HOW MANY TIMES IT'S FOUND A MATCH
// INCREMENT THE COUNTER EACH TIME
// IF THE COUNTER IS 3, RESET IT TO ZERO AND MAKE THE REPLACEMENT
$string = preg_replace_callback('/'.$remove.'/', function($m) use(&$i, $remove, $replace) {$a = $remove; if (++$i == 3) {$i = 0; $a = $replace;} return $a;}, $str);

print $string;
```

This outputs the following:

```
ter-yu-ter-u-mov-hg-ter-as-b-ter-a-sdf-w-mov-s-ter-asd
```

If you do not have a function similar to `preg_replace_callback`, you could probably explode at your search term into segments, breaking it apart at the `remove`.  Then loop through all of your string parts and increment your counter each time.  If the counter divided by three has a remainder of zero, then apply your replacement.

Here's an example using a `foreach`:

```
// SET THE DEFAULTS
$i = 0;
$str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-ter-hg-ter-as-b-ter-a-sdf-w-ter-s-ter-asd';
$remove = 'ter';
$replace = 'mov';
$final_string = ''; // THIS WILL BE OUR OUTPUT STRING LATER

// BREAK APART THE STRING INTO AN ARRAY OF MATCHES, BASED ON THE $remove VALUE
$matches_for_remove = explode($remove, $str);

// LOOP THROUGH EACH ITEM IN THE ARRAY
foreach ($matches_for_remove AS $match) {

    // SET THE DEFAULT STRING TO $remove
    $replacement_string = $remove;
    if (++$i % 3 == 0) { // IF THE REMAINDER IS ZERO, THEN DO THE REPLACEMENT
        $replacement_string = $replace; 
    }

    // IF IT'S NOT THE END, APPEND THE remove OR replace PORTION ON TO THE END
    if ($i == count($matches_for_remove)){
        $final_string .= $match;
    }
    else {
        $final_string .= $match.$replacement_string;
    }

}

print $final_string;
```

And the same example, but using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`:

```
$str = 'ter-yu-ter-u-ter-hg-ter-as-b-ter-a-sdf-w-ter-s-ter-asd';
$remove = 'ter';
$replace = 'mov';
$final_string = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches_for_remove); $i++) {

    $replacement_string = $remove;

    if (($i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        $replacement_string = $replace;
    }

    if ($i == count($matches_for_remove) - 1) {
        $final_string .= $matches_for_remove[$i];
    }
    else {
        $final_string .= $matches_for_remove[$i].$replacement_string;
    }

}

print $final_string;
```

Again, sorry if my examples, written in PHP don't make any sense.  I understand the concept, just not how to translate that into Matlab.  Hopefully though, this will at least get you pointed in the right direction.